# Implementing a simple regex language in Python using recursion

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, recursion

I'll try to make the description as simple as possible.

I am asked to give a solution for the regular expression with only **0**, **1** 
say `0\*` matches nothing or any string with only **0**'s.

I have three operators `.`, `\*`, `|`

- `.` combines two regular expressions **r1** and **r1**, **r1** matches **s1** and **r2** matches `s2, s = s1 + s2`
- `|` is like or, combine r1, r2, either r1 matches s1 or r2 matches s2 would make `(r1|r2) matches s = s1 + s2`
- `\*` is just the star case, none or more logic.

All the operators and 0s and 1s are stored in a binary tree.

For a full reference: http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~heap/148/F13/Assignments/A2/a2.pdf

I am trying to find a recursive solution.

Take `((1.(0|1)\*).0)` (Any string starts with **1** and ends with **0**) matches `100101010` as an example:

The `.` on the right is the root of the regex tree, for its left child `1.(0|1)\*` and right child 0, recursively solve `match('1.(0|1)\*', 10010101)`, for its right child `0`, recursively solve `match('0', 0)`.

for the right child it will return true,

the left part continues the recursive step.

Something like

```
def match(rx, s):
    if rx == s:
         // base case when s is 0 or 1
         return True
    else:
         return False
    x = 'some number'
    s1 = s[:x]
    s2 = s[x:]
    if rx.operator == '.':
       return match(rx.left, s1) and match(rx.right, s2)
    elif rx.operator == '|':
       return match(rx.left, s1) or match(rx.right, s2)
    else:
       return solveStar(rx, s)
```

Two part I am stuck right now, first how should I divide the string to match the sub regular expression, second I am confused on solve the star * case

Comment: Please edit your post to make your code actually readable

Comment: Thanks Joe but I am really new to this so I do not know how to edit it, how should I do it btw, thanks~

Comment: "'|' is like or, combine r1, r2, either r1 matches s1 or r2 matches s2 would make (r1|r2) matches s = s1 + s2" are you sure this bit is correct? This makes it sound like (r1|r2) matches a string s, where s=s1+s2 if either of r1 or r2 match s1 or s2.